# Who is responsible for exterminating cockroaches in house - tenant or landlord?

Tags: halacha, torts-damages, rental

If a rental house is infested with cockroaches, what does the halacha say about who is responsible for hiring an exterminator, the landlord or the tenant?

Answer (score 9):

According to the Rabbi answering same question [this site](http://din.org.il/2014/03/24/%D7%90%D7%9D-%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%A8-%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%91-%D7%9C%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%9D-%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A8-%D7%94%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%94/), if there are no specifications in the rental agreement then it depends:

- If the house is uninhabitable due to the roaches, then the landlord has to pay.
- If it's merely inconvenient then the tenant has to pay.

As to where to draw the line, he answers that if the infestation is so bad that a normal person would hire a Profesional Exterminator to deal with it then the landlord has to pay.

If it's a borderline case then the landlord does not have to pay, though it would be appropriate for him to share in the costs.

The Rabbi answering the question refers one to [this pdf](http://din.org.il/wp-content/uploads/alon_hamishpat/27.pdf) - on page 5 - where it discusses the halachic sources of Tenant vs. Landlord issues with sources.

Comment: I have trouble accessing the article, now (web blocking). I would assume that a large factor is based on what is considered "normal occurrence". In typical New York City apartments, roaches are considered a normal appearance. (Gross, no?) so the tenant has to deal with them. Mice are not considered "normal", so the landlord deals with them.

Comment: @DanF - when I lived in Baltimore it was sometimes hard, in the dark, to tell the difference between a large roach and a small mouse ...

Comment: @DanF - is there a way to upload a PDF to SE?

Comment: I'm unaware of a method to load a full file dirfectly. But, I am able to access the file, now. *Elokei Hashamayim*! I really need to practice my Hebrew to understand this! Esp. since I plan being in Israel soon. I hope your Yerushalmi apt, doesn't have too many jukim.